# Python 3.8 subprocess.run(command) to delete folder and file gets FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: python, subprocess, python-3.8

I'm using python 3.8 on a windows 10 computer to generate with pyinstaller a EXE file via the subprocess.run(command) method. -I'm new to using subprocess-
This part is working

Pyinstaller generates a *.spec file and a builds folders that I wish to delete after the EXE file is  created.
I'm also using subprocess for the delete commands.

My logic is as follows:

```
import os
import subprocess
import sys
import time

file_name = 'Discovery'

# Delete temp files and folders.
print("Deleting temp files...")
time.sleep(5)  # Sleep for 5 seconds
folder_to_delete = '{}/build'.format(os.path.abspath(os.getcwd()))
file_to_delete = '{}/{}.spec'.format(os.path.abspath(os.getcwd()), file_name)

if sys.platform == "win32":
   delete_folder_command = f'rmdir /F/Q/S {folder_to_delete}'
   delete_file_command = f'del {file_to_delete}'
if sys.platform == "darwing":
   delete_folder_command = f'rm -r {folder_to_delete}'
   delete_file_command = f'rm {file_to_delete}'
subprocess.run(delete_folder_command)
subprocess.run(delete_file_command)
```

the build folder and the *.spec file exist

[image]

But I'm getting the following error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

with the tracebak beginning at line

```
subprocess.run(delete_folder_command)
```

I tried formatting the command in various ways with no success.
For example:

```
folder_to_delete = build
file_to_delete = f'{file_name}.spec'
delete_folder_command = f'rmdir /F/Q/S {folder_to_delete}'
delete_file_command = f'del {file_to_delete}'
subprocess.run('cd {}'.format(os.path.abspath(os.getcwd())
subprocess.run(delete_file_command)
subprocess.run(delete_folder_command)
```

in this last case the trace back begins at line

```
subprocess.run('cd {}'.format(os.path.abspath(os.getcwd())
```

It seems to be an issue of the `os.path.abspath(os.getcwd()` but I use it in another place in the logic with no issues on a formatted text.

```
create_exe_file_command = 'pyinstaller -F -w  -i"{}" --add-data="{}/img;." -n"{}" discovery.py'.format(icon_path, os.path.abspath(os.getcwd()),file_name)
```

Maybe I'm blind or just need a second pair of eyes but can't figure out why I get the error.
Appreciated if you could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Can you do `print(delete_folder_command)` to verify the command and filepath are correct? Have you tried this on both platforms, does it work on one but not the other? If so which platform does it not work on?

Comment: @Dillanm, thank you for your comment.
Currently I do not have a macOS machine. This will be tested in the near future.
Regarding printing the delete_folder command and the delete_file_command
yes I get the correct path and command:
```print(delete_folder_command)``` output ```rmdir /S C:\Edumarg\discovery/build```
```print(delete_file_command)``` output ```del C:\Edumarg\discovery/Discovery.spec```

Answer (score 2):

rmdir is implemented in shell interpreter. In order to run it, you need tell subprocess.run that you want to run your commands in shell by passing `shell=True` to it ..

Comment: Thank you rasjani,
it worked for the file bt not the folder
I do not get error message any more but I'm getting the following:
```
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Comment: @edumarg https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html  - you should not pass one string subprocess.run.. you should pass array ..

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to put the commands in a list.
Example: 
In my case I made a folder and inside the folder I made a file. Now the following Code will delete the file first and the folder second.

```
import os
import subprocess

folder_to_delete = 'build'
file = 'Discovery.spec'
file_to_delete = f'{folder_to_delete}/{file}'

base_dir = ['cd', os.path.abspath(os.getcwd())]
folder_command = ['rmdir', folder_to_delete]
file_command = ['rm',file_to_delete ]

subprocess.run(base_dir)
subprocess.run(file_command)
subprocess.run(folder_command)
```

Comment: loannis E. Kommas, thank you four your answer.
Unfortunately I still get the ```FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified``` on line ```subprocess.run(f'cd'.format(os.path.abspath(os.getcwd())))``` even if I change it to ```subprocess.run(['cd', os.path.abspath(os.getcwd())])```

Comment: Dunno m8 what's the problem see my video here <br> https://www.loom.com/share/7cc753c536b34e40973509d08a6544a1.

Comment: Thank you Ioannis E. Kommas, I'll look at the video
I implemented the command as list as you mention and then the shell=True as rasjani mention.
it is working only for the file but not for the folder.

Comment: Ioannis E. Kommas, I notices you are using macOS.
Yes, this is one of the OS I'll need to use in the future and your answer will help me once I start testing in that OS. So thank you very much.
At the moment the issue is with Windows 10.